# Run a specific $match query only if string is not empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to implement a search of documents in a collection.  One of the queries in the $match stage checks if anything in a list matches another list from my JS (not within the document).

However, what I want to do is only run that query if the list has contents.  If it is empty then just ignore it.

Essentially like choosing options in a filter.  If you choose something, then it will search for that, if you choose nothing then it doesn't limit based on that.

Person documents:

```
{
    name: String,
    dob: Date,
    gender: String,
    favoriteColors: [{
        color: String,
        otherInfo: String
    }]
}
```

My pipeline:

```
let colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];

collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        gender: "male",
        //run below only if colors array is not empty
        favoriteColors: {
            $elemMatch: {
                color: {
                    $in: colors
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

How can I basically just run that part of the aggregate only if the array is not empty?  I really don't want to use an if statement and write that same aggregate twice based on the two different conditions.  Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this using [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) like so:

```
let colors = [ ... ]
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                    {
                        $eq: [
                            "$gender",
                            "male"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        $cond: [
                            {
                                $gt: [
                                    colors.length,
                                    0
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $gt: [
                                    {
                                        $size: {
                                            $setIntersection: [
                                                {
                                                    $map: {
                                                        input: "$favoriteColors",
                                                        as: "color",
                                                        in: "$$color.color"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                colors
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    0
                                ]
                            },
                            {}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

But if you're already using code why not move the same logic into js?:

```
let colors = [ ... ];

let conds = [
    {
        "gender": "Male"
    }
];

if (colors.length) {
    conds.push({
        "favoriteColors.color": {$in: colors}
    })
}

db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and: conds
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot.  I hadn't thought about storing conditions in variables to use in the aggregation.  Still kind of learning MongoDB/Mongoose.